# Selecting subset spark dataframe by months

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataset:

[image]

i want to take a 3 month subset of it (eg the months: april, may and august) using pyspark.

I still haven't found anything that would let me near this dataframe using pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the month using [`month()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.month.html?highlight=month#pyspark.sql.functions.month) and then apply a [`isin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html?highlight=isin#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) function to find rows matching the filter criteria.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(1, "2021-01-01", ), (2, "2021-04-01", ), (3, "2021-05-01", ), (4, "2021-06-01", ), (5, "2021-07-01", ), (6, "2021-08-01", ), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("cod_item", "date_emissao", )).withColumn("date_emissao", F.to_date("date_emissao"))

df.filter(F.month("date_emissao").isin(4, 5, 8)).show()

"""
+--------+------------+
|cod_item|date_emissao|
+--------+------------+
|       2|  2021-04-01|
|       3|  2021-05-01|
|       6|  2021-08-01|
+--------+------------+
"""
```